# relative file path not working in Java

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

After reading that is it possible to create a relative filepath name using "../" I tried it out.

I have a relative path for a file set like this:

```
String dir = ".." + File.separator + "web" + File.separator + "main";
```

But when I try setting the file with the code below, I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
File nFile= new File(dir + File.separator + "new.txt");
```

Why is this?

Comment: Can you show us the  directory structure ?

Comment: /dev/app/build is what I get when I print System.getProperty(user.dir) - I want a file inside /dev/app/web/main

Comment: What is the absolute path of `new.txt`?

Comment: @Seephor if your `new.txt` is in root folder then you dont need `../`.

Comment: print `nFile.getAbsolutePath()` and `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` and you'll see what's wrong. The later will print the working directory. See if `dir` is really the parent of `new.txt`, also you could use [File(String parent, String child)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for creating `nFile`

Comment: nFile prints: "C:\dev\app\build\..\web\main" and the ("") file prints "C:\dev\app\build". I am trying to create a file in \dev\app\web\main

Comment: as suggested by @A4L, File(String parent, String child) should work for you, probably with file.getParentFile()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nFile prints: "C:\dev\app\build\..\web\main"

and

> ("") file prints "C:\dev\app\build"

According to your outputs, after you enter `build` you go up 1 time with `..` back to `app` and expect `web` to be there (in the same level as `build`). Make sure that the directory `C:\dev\app\web\main` exists.

You could use [exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to check whether the directory `dir` exist, if not create it using [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Sample code:

```
File parent = new File(dir);
if(! parent.exists()) {
    parents.mkdirs();
}
File nFile = new File(parent, "new.txt");
```

Note that it is possible that the file denoted by `parent` may already exist but is not a directory, in witch case it would not be possible to use it a s parent. The above code does not handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why wont you take the Env-Varable "user.dir"?

It returns you the path, in which the application was started from.

```
System.getProperty(user.dir)+File.separator+"main"+File.separator+[and so on]
```

Comment: System.getProperty(user.dir) gives me a path like /dev/app/build, but I want a file in /dev/app/web/main

Comment: so you start your application from /dev/app/build? you could / should use an starter anyway, so you can create a shellscript starting something like: "java -jar web/main/program.jar"